# Django ORM cannot resolve keyword for related field for aggregate when model used by more than one application

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-related-manager

In Django 1.5 I have 3 apps: common, app1, app2 in which I have the following (simplified) models:

```
# common/models.py
class ApiUser(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    channel = models.CharField(max_length=20)

# app1/models.py
class Place(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('common.ApiUser', null=True, related_name="%(app_label)s_places")

# app2/models.py
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey('common.ApiUser', null=True, related_name="%(app_label)s_tags")
```

`app1` is listed before `app2` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

When I try to create the following queryset:

```
qs = ApiUser.objects.filter(channel='app1').annotate(Count('app1_places'))
```

I get back:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'app1_places' into field. Choices are: app2_tags, channel, username
```

Where the list of choices provided does not include `'app1_places'` but does contain `'app2_tags'`. However if I try to reference `app1_places` on a model instance I don't get an error; it works fine:

```
>>> u = ApiUser.objects.get(pk=23)
>>> u.app1_places.all()
[]
```

Annotate with `app2_tags` works too:

```
qs = ApiUser.objects.filter(channel='app2').annotate(Count('app2_tags'))
```

Is this a bug in django or is there something I am doing wrong configuring these fields.

**edit**: here is the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/thorium/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 795, in annotate
    is_summary=False)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/thorium/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1019, in add_aggregate
field_list, opts, self.get_initial_alias(), False)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/thorium/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1337, in setup_joins
  "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(names)))
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'app1_places' into field. Choices are: app2_tags, channel, username
```

**Note:** some app1 models are using the GeoDjango GeoManager (including places) but there are also models in app1 which don't use the geomanager and have foreign keys that also do not work with annotate.

Comment: Does it fix itself if you swap the order of app1 and app2 in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Do you have a method or property in ApiUser with the name equals to the `related_name`?

Comment: @hack.augusto: That would probably break `u.app1_places.all()` too.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone no it doesn't in fact nothing changes

Comment: What's your full error message?  `Cannot resolve keyword 'app1_places' into field. Choices are: ...` Please list the choices!

Comment: @Leonardo.Z I have added the stacktrace

Comment: I just created a test application with the same models and did not get any errors

Comment: @hack.augusto: Which Django version? rojoca's might be out of date.

Comment: @hack.augusto I don't have a `tags_set` option. I have tried adding ForeignKey fields to other models in app1 and get the same issue.

Comment: @Mike, latest (1.5.5), just created a virtualenv and did a `pip install django` with python 2.7.5

Comment: I am using python 2.6.5

Comment: @rojoca, Python 2.6.5 in theory should not be a problem, [the docs says that this version is supported](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/install/#install-python)

Comment: @rojoca Are you using Django 1.5.5, 1.5, or some other bugfix?

Comment: @MikeDeSimone I am using Django 1.5.2

Comment: Check the bug fixes up to 1.5.5. If you're having the problem and hack isn't, I'm betting it's been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with a proxy model that was on app1 and not app2. The proxy model had a custom manager:

```
# app1/models.py
class App1User(common_models.ApiUser):
    objects = common_models.ApiUser.objects.filter(channel='app1')

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

App2 is not using a corresponding proxy model for ApiUser. When django first loads all the models to determine the model domain and calculate backwards references the overridden manager in the proxy model short-circuited the loading of app1.models, leaving all the backwards references for that module uninitialised.

Removing the custom manager definition resolved the issue.